# How to extract text after second space in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Example value: Becky G Smith

I can already get the first name of everybody in Column A and put the result in Column B with this:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
x = InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")
y = InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, "@")

If InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ") > 0 Then
Cells(i, "B").Value = Left(Cells(i, "A"), x - 1)
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, "@") > 0 Then
Cells(i, "B").Value = Left(Cells(i, "A"), y - 1)
End If

Next i
```

The `ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, "@") > 0 Then` statement is there because sometimes I'm dealing with emails, like Becky@gmail.com

The problem is getting "Smith" as her last name. I don't want the middle initial. I've tried this for getting the last name:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
w = InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")
x = InStr(w, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")
y = InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, "@")
Z = Len(Cells(i, "A").Value)

If InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ") > 0 Then
Cells(i, "C").Value = Right(Cells(i, "A"), Z - x)
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(i, "A").Value, "@") > 0 Then
Cells(i, "C").Value = Right(Cells(i, "A"), Z - y)
End If

Next i
```

But ultimately the `w` in `x = InStr(w, Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")` brings up a bug. Apparently VBA considers `w` to equal 0. So I need a way of extracting the text after the second space.

Comment: Go backwards (from the right)? Then you only need to find first space.

Comment: Last Name = `split(cells(i, "A").value," ")(2)`.  This only works if the there is always a middle initial/name.  Or you could load the whole into an array and grab the last one.

Comment: @ScottCraner Does this function output anything? Or is it just creating a temporary array?

Comment: The split function will load an array.  With what I typed it will return the third entry as a string.  It only works if there is always three names.  Look at bas's answer.  You could change his function easily to also get the first name.

Comment: Hmm well that doesn't really work, since sometimes there's only one name, sometimes there are two names, and sometimes there are 3.

Comment: If there is only one, how do you know if it is a first or last name?

Comment: I assume that it's a first name and manually review it later. It's not really relevant to the programming question here though

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetLastName(sName As String) As String

    Dim aWords()    As String

    aWords = Split(sName, " ")

    GetLastName = aWords(UBound(aWords))

End Function
```

You can just use it in your sheet

Comment: Just for giggles, show the OP how you would write a new function to get the first name.  Also so how he would call this function.

Comment: Or a function that does both with a parameter passed in.